# Getting wrong answer for Project Euler #27

Tags: c++

I'm working on Project Euler #27 in C++:

> Euler published the remarkable quadratic formula:
>
> n² + n + 41
>
> It turns out that the formula will produce 40 primes for the
>   consecutive values n = 0 to 39. However, when n = 40, 40² + 40 + 41 =
>   40(40 + 1) + 41 is divisible by 41, and certainly when n = 41, 41² +
>   41 + 41 is clearly divisible by 41.
>
> Using computers, the incredible formula  n² − 79n + 1601 was
>   discovered, which produces 80 primes for the consecutive values n = 0
>   to 79. The product of the coefficients, −79 and 1601, is −126479.
>
> Considering quadratics of the form:
>
> ```
> n² + an + b, where |a| < 1000 and |b| < 1000
>
> where |n| is the modulus/absolute value of n
> e.g. |11| = 11 and |−4| = 4
> ```
>
> Find the product of the coefficients, a and b, for the quadratic
>   expression that produces the maximum number of primes for consecutive
>   values of n, starting with n = 0.

I keep getting -60939 when the real answer is -59231. What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Helper.h"
using namespace std;

int formula(int a, int b, int n) {
    return ((n * n) + (a * n) + b);
}

int main() {
    int most = 0;
    int ansA = 0;
    int ansB = 0;
    bool end = false;

    for(int a = 999; a >= -999; a--) {
        for(int b = 999; b >= 2; b--) { //b must be prime
            if(Helper::isPrime(b)) {
                end = false;
                for(int n = 0; !end; n++) {
                    if(!Helper::isPrime(formula(a, b, n))) {
                        if(n-1 > most) {
                            most = n-1;
                            ansA = a;
                            ansB = b;
                        }
                        end = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << ansA << " * " << ansB << " = " << ansA * ansB << " with " << most << " primes." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In case it's the problem, here is my isPrime function:

```
bool Helper::isPrime(int num) {
    if(num == 2)
        return true;

    if(num % 2 == 0 || num == 1 || num == 0)
        return false;

    int root = (int) sqrt((double)num) + 1;
    for(int i = root; i >= 2; i--) {
        if (num % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think the `n-1` part is wrong: If the answer for `n==0` is prime but 1 isn't, then when you get to iteration one and drop out of the loop you'll say `most = 0` when it's really one. This doesn't appear to be the source of  your other problem though.

Comment: I copied your code and ran in C# with my IsPrime and got the right answer.  So either your isPrime method is flawed or the way C++ handles `formula(a, b, n)` isn't what you expect.

Comment: I added my isPrime just in case.

Comment: It would be faster to swap the `for a` and `for b` loops so that `isPrime(b)` is only called once for each `b`, and not 1999 times...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allowing `a` to be negative, and your `formula` returns an int. Does calling Helper::isPrime with a negative number even make sense (in other words, does Helper::isPrime take an unsigned int?)

Comment: Thank you! All I needed to add to isPrime was `if(num < 0) num *= -1;`

Comment: +1 That's it, if you change the OP's isPrime to return false for negative numbers then it generates the expected answer.

Comment: @paperbd: What you should have done was to reject negative numbers as prime. The first prime is 2.

Comment: Right, I'll just change it so it returns false if < 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my java version. Hope it helps:

```
static int function(int n, int a, int b){
    return n*n + a*n + b;
}
static int consequitive_Primes(int a, int b, HashSet<Integer> primes){
    int n = 0;
    int number = 0;
    while(true){
        if(!primes.contains(function(n, a, b)))
            break;
        number++;
        n++;
    }
    return number;
}
static HashSet<Integer> primes (int n){
    ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    primes.add(3);
    for(int i=3; i<n;i+=2){
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for(Integer k:primes){
            if(i%k==0){
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime) primes.add(i);
    }
    return new HashSet<Integer>(primes);
}
static long q27(){
    HashSet<Integer> primes = primes(1000);
    int max = 0;
    int max_ab = 0;
    for(int a = -999; a<1000;a++){
        for(int b = -999; b<1000;b++){
            int prime_No = consequitive_Primes(a,b,primes);
            if(max<prime_No){
                max = prime_No;
                max_ab = a*b;
            }
        }
    }
    return max_ab;
}
```